# Vmware windows 10 installation screen displayed when expecting windows

Tags: windows, vmware

I have VMware and windows 10 installed on a virtual machine on my Macbook Pro. I have an ISO file of windows 10 mounted and sometimes when I restart windows and expect it to restart I'm prompted with the "install windows screen" instead.

It scares the shit out of me. Why is this happening? There seem to be some kind of delay as it seems to auto-magically open windows when I try again.

This morning I thought I had to restart windows all over again and go through 3 days of headache (setting up / installing programs etc), but then I went on a meeting and then it worked. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the BIOS boot order to ignore the CD-ROM should fix the issue.

However, is there any reason you have the ISO mounted still?

Answer (score 0):

I think it was the iso file on the host, it is mounted. And delete your snapshots.

Comment: Hm I'm not quite sure I follow. Shouldn¨t the iso file be mounted? Sounds too risky to me to just delete my snapshots without further investigation for the time being..